# Parse JSON array with PHP script

Tags: php, json

I try to read a JSON object and parse it. The code that I'm using is the following one:

```
<?php

$json_string2 = '{"Products":[
                    {"Size":"klklkkl",
                        "No":"1352285923",
                        "KnowDate":true,
                        "Subdata":[
                        {
                            "item" : "1",
                        },
                        {
                            "item" : "455",
                        }],
                        "Info":true
                    }]
                }';

$obj = json_decode($json_string2, true);

foreach($obj as $key => $value)
{
    $size = $value->{'Size'};
    $no = $value->{'No'};
    $knowdate = $value->{'KnowDate'};
    $info = $value->{'Info'};
}
.
.
?>
```

But in the line into the for loop i receive the following error:

```
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\PhpProject2\parseJson.php on line...
```

What is the solution to this problem?Does anyone knows?

Comment: Have you tried a good-old var_dump? var_dump($obj); above your foreach loop.

Comment: Which line is issuing that notice? Do a `var_dump($obj)` to see exactly what you're getting and how to reference it.

Comment: Throw in a `var_dump($obj);` just before the `foreach` and post what it returns?

Comment: Could it be that in the `foreach` you need to reference the properties with `$value['<key>']` instead of `$value->{'<key>'}`?

Comment: So you can see why the loop is failing? You need to loop through the products array... foreach($obj[products]...)

Answer (score 2):

Either pass `true` as the second parameter to [`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) function and use the array notation:

```
$obj = json_decode($json_string2, true);
foreach ($obj['Products'] as $key => $value) {
    $size = $value['Size'];
    $no   = $value['No'];
}
```

Or pass `false` (or do not pass the second parameter) and use the object notation:

```
$obj = json_decode($json_string2 /*,false*/ );
foreach ($obj->{'Products'} as $key => $value) {
    $size = $value->{'Size'};
    $no   = $value->{'No'};
}
```

Note: there were other issues with your code (i) broken JSON (ii) not iterating over the right key.

Comment: You don't necessarily need to pass in false as an argument to have the JSON decoded as an object.

Comment: That loop is going to fail, BTW. You need to loop through $obj['prodcuts'] in your first example, or $obj->products in the second example.

Answer (score 1):

You should try `var_dump`. You get the following structure:

```
array(1) {
  ["Products"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    array(5) {
      ["Size"]=>
      string(7) "klklkkl"
      ["No"]=>
      string(10) "1352285923"
      ["KnowDate"]=>
      bool(true)
      ["Subdata"]=>
      array(2) {
        [0]=>
        array(1) {
          ["item"]=>
          string(1) "1"
        }
        [1]=>
        array(1) {
          ["item"]=>
          string(3) "455"
        }
      }
      ["Info"]=>
      bool(true)
    }
  }
}
```

When you iterate with `foreach`, you get `$key` as `"Products"`, and `$value` as the array of products.

What you're probably looking for is `foreach($obj['Products'] as $key=>$value)`

And because you have arrays, not objects, you need to use these square brackets everywhere inside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

The JSON is not valid because you have commas before closing braces:

```
   "item" : "1",
 },
 {
    "item" : "455",
 }
```

Note the commas after "1" and "455"

Even if you correct this, you must loop over `$obj->Products`.

Comment: $obj is not an object because of the second argument he is passing into json_encode...

Comment: @MatthewBlancarte the JSON is invalid regardless